# Angular 16 application fails to build in Docker but builds locally

Tags: angular, docker

Trying to build an Angular 16 application with this Dockerfile (based in [this reference](https://serengetitech.com/tech/how-to-dockerize-your-angular-14-application/), adapting it slightly):

```
FROM node:18.16-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/dist

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
COPY package-lock.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The `npm run build` commands results in this error log:

```
2023-05-18T10:37:25Z #13 [8/8] RUN npm run build
2023-05-18T10:37:26Z #13 1.289
2023-05-18T10:37:26Z #13 1.289 > urbo@2.18.0-next build
2023-05-18T10:37:26Z #13 1.289 > npx nx run urbo:build
2023-05-18T10:37:26Z #13 1.289
2023-05-18T10:37:29Z #13 4.731
2023-05-18T10:37:30Z #13 4.732 > nx run urbo:build:production
2023-05-18T10:37:30Z #13 4.732
2023-05-18T10:37:33Z #13 8.411 - Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
2023-05-18T10:37:45Z #13 20.63 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.76 ✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 ./apps/urbo/src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/noSourceMaps.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 ./node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 ./apps/urbo/src/styles.scss?ngGlobalStyle - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 HookWebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js):
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.77
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.93
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.93
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.93
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.93 > NX Running target build for project urbo failed
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.93
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.94 Failed tasks:
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.94
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.94 - urbo:build:production
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.94
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.94 Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 20.94
2023-05-18T10:37:46Z #13 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c npm run build]: exit code: 1
```

The surprising think is that if I try to build locally (i.e. without Docker) it builds as expected:

```
$ npm run build

> urbo@2.18.0-next build
> npx nx run urbo:build


> nx run urbo:build:production  [local cache]


Initial Chunk Files           | Names         |  Raw Size | Estimated Transfer Size
main.488489d057079c5a.js      | main          | 171.32 kB |                46.52 kB
polyfills.009d9a8ff651280a.js | polyfills     |  32.98 kB |                10.63 kB
styles.42447b8cfc638971.css   | styles        |   5.35 kB |                 1.15 kB
runtime.6cd79f8b99697142.js   | runtime       | 886 bytes |               514 bytes

                              | Initial Total | 210.52 kB |                58.80 kB

Build at: 2023-05-17T14:47:20.385Z - Hash: 3d6bc33d2b4daeec - Time: 160564ms

 ———————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————

 >  NX   Successfully ran target build for project urbo (1s)
 
   Nx read the output from the cache instead of running the command for 1 out of 1 tasks.
```

I don't know how to identify the environment differences or debug this any further. I have tried to Google the error messages I get but it haven't been able to find any valuable help.

Comment: your Dockerfile syntax looks fine, my bet - the image causes the error, maybe try to rebuild your dockerfile over a different image such as alpine or FROM node:16-alpine like suggested in the manual you linked here.

Comment: I would also maybe throw in a `RUN ls` line just to make sure your working directory is looking as expected. My guess is that it's possibly the image like @Shachar297 mentioned, but failing that, the output of `ls` might shed some light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end the problem was in the `packages-lock.json` file.

After regenerating that file (doing `rm packages-lock.json ; npm install`) the application started correctly.